# What is a reference in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20

While investigating the difference between lvalue reference and rvalue reference I found a [useful page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) with strict definitions of what lvalue and rvalue are.

Now, assuming I know what lvalue and rvalue are, where can I find the definitions of lvalue reference and rvalue reference?

Is there some general definition of a reference that can be applied to both lvalue and rvalue? I other words is there some general term for `&` and `&&`?

Comment: A reference is an alias.  A lvalue reference is a reference to a lvalue, a rvalue reference is a reference to a rvalue.

Comment: Here you go [Reference initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)

Comment: _"is there some general term for & and &&?"_  Yes, the term is _reference_.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Have you read the [`reference declaration` doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) that is on the same site you read the [`value categories` doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) on?

Comment: @DrewDormann good comment :), where is it defined?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I think you're looking for [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1), if you're looking for something authoritative.